# ¿Cómo hacer consultas a PostgreSQL usando Bitnami WAPP?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, postgresql

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación hecha en Laravel con una Base de Datos PostgreSQL en Window 10, para correr la aplicación Lavarel instale [Bitnami WAPP](https://bitnami.com/stack/wapp) que viene con PHP y PostgresSQL, sin embargo no estoy seguro como hacer consultas directamente a PostgreSQL desde Laravel, en la documentación de Bitnami dice usar el comando: `psql -U postgresql`, pero la cmd me responde `"psql" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo, programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.` y desde `phppgadmin` tampoco es posible hacer consultas como en `phpmyadmin`

Comment: En el menú de inicio Bitnami WAPP -> Application console es posible correr comandos directos, en el caso de Postgres debería ser: /opt/bitnami/pgsql/bin/psql https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/wapp/administration/run-command/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por si alguien más no sabe como hacerlo, lo que hay hacer para correr postgresql desde el cmd de window, es agregar a la variable de entorno `Path`, el acceso de los comando de postgresql como mencionan en el comentario de arriba. Las rutas que que hay que agregar a `Path`, son `C:\Bitnami\wappstackversion\postgresql\bin` y `C:\Bitnami\wappstackversion\postgresql\lib`, con las rutas agregadas será posible correr postgresql desde la cmd de windows, para comprobarlo se puede ejecutar `psql -U postgres`